# How to get bookmark history of Internet app on android by my app?

Tags: android

I want to get history of Internet app (Web Browser) on android by my app, I try using with "com.android.browser.permission.READ_HISTORY_BOOKMARKS"

But it only support for OS < 6.0. Do you have a new method to get history? Please help me! Thanks.

Comment: firstly, that app has to support it. What is that `Internet app`? Why do you think that it should give you it's history?

Comment: Internet app is a browser default on android phone? I want to get history, bookmark to backup.

Comment: which browser exactly? there are maybe 500 browser apps available on Android.

Comment: It is Samsung Internet, Chrome Browser.

Answer (score 1):

Use an ArrayList.

```
String title = "";
    String url = "";

    ArrayList<HistoryEntry> list = new ArrayList<HistoryEntry>();

    String[] proj = new String[] { Browser.BookmarkColumns.TITLE,
            Browser.BookmarkColumns.URL };
    String sel = Browser.BookmarkColumns.BOOKMARK + " = 0"; 

    Cursor mCur = getContentResolver().query(Browser.BOOKMARKS_URI, proj,
            sel, null, null);
    mCur.moveToFirst();

    if (mCur.moveToFirst() && mCur.getCount() > 0) {
        boolean cont = true;
        while (mCur.isAfterLast() == false && cont) {
            HistoryEntry entry = new HistoryEntry();

            title = mCur.getString(mCur
                    .getColumnIndex(Browser.BookmarkColumns.TITLE));
            url = mCur.getString(mCur
                    .getColumnIndex(Browser.BookmarkColumns.URL));
            entry.setTitle(title);
                            entry.setUrl(url);
                            list.add(entry );
            Log.d("TAG", "title   " + title);
            mCur.moveToNext();
        }
    }

    mCur.close();

    return list;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your sharing. Your method only support for OS < 6.0. I want to use all OS. Do you have other method.